# Custom error messages from queries based on data in the collection in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm wondering if there's a way to return custom errors and/or messages from queries depending on the data in the dataset in mongodb.

For example and clarification, consider that I have the following collection, named `users`, with data in this format:

```
{
     "_id": "65506e0b9ab7d8f1f9e23373",
     "first_name": "John",
     "last_name": "Smith",
     "age": 33,
     "occupation": "Software engineer",
     "is_active": false,
}
```

And I would like to change the `occupation` field **if** the `_id` field matches **AND** the `is_active` field is true, however, I would also like to know the reason why the document wasn't updated if it wasn't.

One way to do this of course is by fetching the document that matches the `_id` field then validate (using programming language code) if the field `is_active == true` and if it is, then use an update query to update the `occupation` field, but it seems wasteful to me to make two queries for a simple update.

The logic I'm looking for in a `SINGLE` query is something similar to:

```
if there is a document with _id that matches then:
    if document.is_active == false:
        return CUSTOM_INACTIVE_USER_ERROR
    else:
        update document.occupation to the new value
```

the `CUSTOM_INACTIVE_USER_ERROR` can be a JSON document for example:

```
{
     "error": "in_active is set to false, can't update"
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/waI6CgnHFn3  . try like this? does the update query give back the updated entry. if so you can compare and build the custom error message